# Modify XML TSQL data type

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have the following XML:

```
declare @XML xml
set @XML = '<root>
<ati id_ati="16546" />
</root>'
```

And I have this result select query:

```
[id_ati]
344
566
788
545
```

I want to modify the @XML to:

```
<root>
    <ati id_ati="16546" />
    <ati id_ati="344" />
    <ati id_ati="566" />
    <ati id_ati="788" />
    <ati id_ati="545" />
</root>
```

How to do this?

Tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify a XML variable with [insert (XML DML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175466).

Build the XML you want to insert to a new XML variable and then insert that XML to your XML variable using [`sql:variable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254).

```sql
-- XML to change
declare @XML xml
set @XML = 
'<root>
   <ati id_ati="16546" />
 </root>'

-- Table holding data to insert
declare @T table(id_ati int)
insert into @T values(344),(566),(788),(545)

-- Build the XML you want to add
declare @X xml
set @X =
  (
  select id_ati as "@id_ati"
  from @T
  for xml path('ati')
  )

-- Modify your XML
set @XML.modify('insert sql:variable("@X") as last into root[1]')

-- View the result
select @XML
```

Replace the table variable `@T` with whatever query you have to get the data.
The XML in `@X` looks like this:

```xml
<ati id_ati="344" />
<ati id_ati="566" />
<ati id_ati="788" />
<ati id_ati="545" />
```